# How to update values in map datatype in cloud firestore using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: form picture]

[image: firestore screenshot]
I'm getting the values in the form using jquery, and all values are correctly fetched, now I'm trying to update the values in the fields but I'm unable to do that, I'm attaching the screenshot of form and also of firestore. When I update the values for example sStemElement field which is in the Form map field, it gets updated but the updated value is out of the Form (map) field

**js:**

```
 function updateForm(form, type){
       var name = $('#name_'+type).val();
      var type = $('#type_'+type).val();
      var sStemElement = $('#sStemElement').prop('checked');
       console.log(name, type, sStemElement);

const taskForm = document.getElementById("taskform");
    let editStatus = false;
    let id = '';


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async (e) => {

    db.collection('Buildings').doc(buildingID).collection('rooms').doc(roomID).collection('objects').doc(objectID).get().then(doc=>{
        const task = doc.data();
       
       id = doc.id;
       editStatus = true;
       document.getElementById('type_Shutter').value = task.type_Shutter;
       document.getElementById('name_Shutter').value = task.name_Shutter;
       document.getElementById('sStemElement').value = task.sStemElement;
     
    })

    btnsEdit.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
        try {
          const doc = await getTask(e.target.dataset.id);
          const task = doc.data();
          taskForm["type_Shutter"].value = task.type_Shutter;
          taskForm["name_Shutter"].value = task.name_Shutter;
          taskForm["sStemElement"].value = task.sStemElement;  
          
            
          editStatus = true;
          id = doc.id;
          taskForm["btn-update-data"].innerText = "Update";

        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    });

});


      taskForm.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

       var type_Shutter = document.getElementById('type_Shutter').value;
      var name_Shutter = document.getElementById('name_Shutter').value;  
       var sStemElement = document.getElementById('sStemElement').value;
    
    

  try {
    if (!editStatus) {
     
  

        var update_data = db.collection('Buildings').doc(buildingID).collection('rooms').doc(roomID).collection('objects').doc(objectID);
          update_data.update({
              type_Shutter:type_Shutter,
              name_Shutter:name_Shutter,
              sStemElement:sStemElement,
            
          }, {merge: true});
        } else {
          await updateTask(id, {
              type_Shutter:type_Shutter,
              name_Shutter:name_Shutter,
              sStemElement:sStemElement,
           
          })
    
          editStatus = false;
          id = '';
          taskForm['btn-update-data'].innerText = 'Updated';
          
            swal("", "DATA UPDATED!", "success");
        }
    
        taskForm.reset();
        title.focus();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of fields which is hard to understand but I don't see any reference to the Form field if you trying to update that.

```
var update_data = db.collection('Buildings').doc(buildingID).collection('rooms').doc(roomID).collection('objects').doc(objectID);
update_data.update({
  type_Shutter:type_Shutter,
  name_Shutter:name_Shutter,
  sStemElement:sStemElement,            
}, {merge: true});
```

I cannot see any field called `Form` in this but it is in your screenshot. So all the fields in the update function will be added out of the form field.

To update anything in the Form field you can try something like:

```
// const docRef = //Reference to that document
docRef.update({ "Form.sAluminum": true })
```

This will update only that field in the Form field.